# Custom category attribute not showing back end

Tags: magento-1.8, category-attribute

I have a small module that creates an attribute for categories. Works fine on my dev site but not on my live.

I can see the module in system>config>advanced>advanced and it is enabled.

I can't see the attribute in the catalog_eav_attribute table and it's not showing in category details on the back end.

I can see the set up entry in the core_resource table.

I have flushed all caches and reindexed but no joy. Any ideas on what might be wrong?